# javascript does not for some reason want to execute on my machine

Tags: javascript

I started using atom as my editor for learning Javascript. I've followed a bunch of tutorials online and while my code looks exactly like it does in the tuts, for some reason I'm missing the Javascript behavior. Here is a simple example of my code that simply won't run out of atom, notepadd++ or notepad. In atom I use the atom-live-server, in notepadd i basiclaly open it on local host. ANyoe have any idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form name="login">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="UserID"><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="Pass"><br>
      <input type ="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
   </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      function check(form){
         if(form.userId.value=="" || form.pass.value==""){
            alert("BLAHBLAHBLAH")
         }
      }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @Jonasw the thing is tutorial that i'm following has identical code. I've also checked it by doing document.GetElementByID("WhatEvID") in that case i was assigning ID to UserID and Pass and that didn't work either

Comment: @Carcigenicate how do i do that

Comment: With the page open, open the developer tools of your browser (usually by pressing F12), go to the console, then run the code. You should usually have the console open while testing JS code.

Comment: `UserID !== userId`, JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method :

- Specify ID's as well to the inputs.
- Pass the button to the function.
- Get the parent of the button (the `<form>`).
- Get the `#UserID` and `#Pass` values using `querySelector` and `value`.

```html
<form name="login">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="UserID" name="UserID"><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="Pass" name="Pass"><br>
  <input type ="button" onclick="check(this)" value="Login"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function check(button){
  var parent=button.parentNode;
  if(parent.querySelector('#UserID').value=="" || parent.querySelector('#Pass').value==""){
    alert("BLAHBLAHBLAH")
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you not considering character's case sensitivity. `userId` and `UserId` are considered different. Therefore `form` is not able to find the reference to the `UserId` element and therefore erroring out. Please check the console output of the browser's developer tools to see the error. Following is the fixed code.

```
<p>Document</p>
<form name="login">
<input name="UserID" type="text" placeholder="Username" /><br /> 
<input name="Pass" type="text" placeholder="Password" /><br /> 
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="check(this.form)" /></form>
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function check(form){
  console.log('FORM', form)
    if(form.UserID.value=="" || form.Pass.value==""){
  alert("BLAHBLAHBLAH")
}
}
// ]]></script>
</p>

    <p>Document</p>
<form name="login">
<input name="UserID" type="text" placeholder="Username" /><br /> 
<input name="Pass" type="text" placeholder="Password" /><br /> 
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="check(this.form)" /></form>
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function check(form){
    if(form.UserID.value=="" || form.Pass.value==""){
      alert("BLAHBLAHBLAH")
    }
}
// ]]></script>
</p>
```